# check box and the text are on different line. how can i put them on same line?

Tags: vb.net

Check box and the text are on different line. How can i put them on same line?

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="p" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem><div style="background-color:green">test1</div></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem><div style="background-color:yellow">test2</div></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using span instead of div?

Answer (score 1):

Since DIVs aren't really supposed to go inside List items, another alternative is to style them with CSS, e.g.

```
<style>
    label[for=p_0] {background-color:green}
    label[for=p_1] {background-color:yellow}
</style>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="p" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Test2" >Test1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Test2">Test 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```